# How to format single textview like below in android without using \n or html format?

Tags: android, textview, string-formatting

**This type of formatting i need i don't want to use \n or br because my string is dynamic and i want to fix any text in this this format**

```
    This is my first textview
        This is my second 
          textview this 
           is my third
            textview
```

Comment: Add string with \n and Make gravity of textview center

Comment: I know this solution but my string is not fix it is dynamic and i just want to fit text in this formate @Reena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programmatically using this function

```
val text = "This is my first text view this is my second textview this is my third textview"
textView.text = proxyWifi.textFormation(text)
```

copy/paste this code do your project :)

```
public String textFormation(String text){
    String result = "";
    String[] sentenceWords = text.split(" ");
    List<String> newSentenceWords = new ArrayList<>();
    textRec(sentenceWords, newSentenceWords, sentenceWords.length -1, 0, "");

    int spacing = 0;
    for(int i = newSentenceWords.size() -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        if(i == newSentenceWords.size() -1)
            result = newSentenceWords.get(i);
        else{
            result += "\n";
            spacing += (newSentenceWords.get(i + 1).length() - newSentenceWords.get(i).length())/2;

            for(int j = 0 ; j < spacing ; j++){
                result += " ";
            }

            result += newSentenceWords.get(i);
        }
    }

    return result;

}

public void textRec(String[] words, List<String> newWords, int indexWords, int indexNewWords, String sentence){
    Log.e("sentence", sentence);
    if(indexWords >= 0){
        if(indexNewWords == 0) {
            newWords.add(words[indexWords]);
            textRec(words, newWords, indexWords - 1, ++indexNewWords, "");
        }else{
            if(newWords.get(indexNewWords - 1).length() >= sentence.length())
                if(sentence.isEmpty())
                    textRec(words, newWords, indexWords - 1, indexNewWords, words[indexWords]);
                else
                    textRec(words, newWords, indexWords - 1, indexNewWords,  words[indexWords] + " " + sentence);
            else {
                newWords.add(sentence);
                textRec(words, newWords, indexWords , ++indexNewWords, "");
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(sentence.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }else{
            newWords.set(indexNewWords - 1 ,sentence + " " + newWords.get(indexNewWords - 1)) ;
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no default implementation for this. Also, you can't find the line number to do this.
So you have to split the sentence into multi lines.Use `\n` for next line. Set **gravity center** to your **textView**.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if you use \n then your next line will be start from      

   This is my first textview
   <here> 
        <not here>
```

So, basically you need multiple TextViews.

**First** devide your text String to multiple parts(Note:- (n+1)th part should be less than nth part and deff. should be both end space).

**Second** Create a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and center gravity.

**Third** loop on that array.
      and in loop create a new textview with gravity center, and set the text to it. 
      and add this TV to linearLayout.

**thats it.**

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give you result as you want

This may work

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.ap.mytestingapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/strTV"
        android:text="hello world!"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strTV);

        //pass string whatever you want to show
        String apStr = printString("This is my first textview This is my second textview this is my third textview");

        //you need to define text size according to your requirement
        // I took here 25

        tv.setTextSize(25);
        tv.setText(apStr);
    }

    private String printString(String responseString) {

        String str = responseString;
        String resultStr = "";

        //you need to define cutLength Value according to your textView's textSize
        // I took it 35 when textView's textSize is 25

        int cutLength = 35;
        int count = 0;
        int from = 0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++){

            //increment of count
            count++;

            //check count value with cutLength so that we can add \n to string
            if(count == cutLength){

                // adding \n to substring
                resultStr = resultStr + str.substring(from, i) + "\n";

                // assigning from = i
                from = i;

                // reduce cutLength value
                cutLength = cutLength-10;

                // assigning count = 0
                count = 0;

            } else if(i == str.length()-1){

                // adding \n to substring
                resultStr = resultStr + str.substring(from) + "\n";
            }

        }

        //return resulting string
        return resultStr;
    }
}
```